# Finite dimensional normed vector spaces are smooth manifolds

Tags: vector-spaces, manifolds

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional (with dimension $n$) normed vector space. I want to  show that $V$ is a smooth manifold. Firstly is following correct?

Firstly, $V$ is a topological space where the topology is naturally induced by the norm on $V$, in fact it doesn't matter what norm we choose, the topology will be the same regardless. Let $V$ have a basis ${v_1,...,v_n}$ and let $\varphi :V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n} $ be the canonical linear isomorphism which maps each vector $v \in V$ to its basis representation. It is a homeomorphism because it is continuous and bijective. So not only are $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n} $ isomorphic as vector spaces, they are also homeomorphic as topological spaces. This shows that $V$ is locally Euclidean, second-countable, and Hausdorff, because all three are topological properties.

The hard part is showing its smooth. How is this done?

Comment: Hmm, well if all you want to show is that $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a smooth structure, why not consider the standard smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$? (Of course, you should not expect the norm to be smooth in general). I guess you are learning the subject. Basically, you should just be aware that the norm itself does not favor a smooth structure (as far as I know), though as you say, it does induce a preferred topological space structure. Also be aware that for some values of $n$, there are some exotic smooth structures (smooth structures that are not equivalent to the standard one).

Comment: So the question should really be, show that any finite dimensional normed vector space admits a smooth structure which is compatible with the topological space structure induced by the norm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Consider any two linear isomorphisms $\varphi,\varphi'\colon V\to\mathbb R^n$. What can you say about the transition map $\varphi'\circ\varphi^{-1}$?

Comment: since $\varphi$ is linear isomorphism, it implies that $\varphi$ are also homeomorphism. Then $(V,\varphi)$ is an atlas of $V$. So the only transition function of  $V$ is $\varphi\circ\varphi^{-1}=id_{\mathbb R^n}$, which is a smooth map on $\mathbb R^n$. By definition of smooth manifold, we deduce that $V$ is a smooth manifold.